Effect of Variable Disaggregation on Other Coefficients
Suppose that I do a multivariate regression of variable $Y$ on variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_k$ and find coefficients $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots \beta_k$.
Consider that variable $X_n$ can be dis-aggregated into $X_{n, 1}, X_{n, 2} \ldots X_{n, l}$ such that while $X_n$ and $X_m$ have low correlation, $X_{j, n}$ and $X_m$ have higher correlation for some values of $j$.
Then if I do multivariate regression of variable $Y$ on the same variables, except with $X_n$ fully dis-aggregated, how will that affect the coefficient $(\beta_m)$ on $X_m$? I'm, in particular, curious if it would show a higher effect. If it would, then what is (a) the mathematical way to under this and (b) the intution.
